# Second Monitor suddenly not detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I installed Ubuntu v22.04 about 3 weeks ago and on the same day, selected and installed the Nividia 535 driver and was using it until now without any issues.

This morning, I boot up my PC, and only one monitor is detected. Since I have a dual boot, I tried windows and the second monitor works fine with no issues on there.

I also tried selecting different Nvidia drivers from the list in Additional drivers. None of them work.

I also tried the following commands and rebooting, taken from questions with the same problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

It didn't work either.

I just tried selecting the X.Org X Server -- Nouveau display driver and rebooted and my second monitor is working as I type this question. However, I am aware that Nvidia drivers have much better performance so would like to know what I can do to fix this issue.